# nrpe: command mysql_check not defined

Tags: mysql, linux, nagios, nrpe

I'm trying to check mysql and tomcat on localhost.
Basically I need to check the ports to see the applications are listening.
I have nrpe and nagios plugins installed
I'm trying to use nrpe to check mysql on localhost, but nagios shows this error: NRPE: command check_mysql not defined

Any idea please?

```
# Define a host for the local machine
define host{
        use                     linux-server            ; Name of host template to use
                            ; This host definition will inherit all variables that are defined
                            ; in (or inherited by) the linux-server host template definition.
        host_name               myserver01
        alias                   localhost
        address                 127.0.0.1
        }
# Define an optional hostgroup for Linux machines
define hostgroup{
        hostgroup_name  linux-servers ; The name of the hostgroup
        alias           Linux Servers ; Long name of the group
        members         myserver01     ; Comma separated list of hosts that belong to this group
        }
# Define a service to "ping" the local machine
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       myserver01
        service_description             PING
    check_command           check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%
        }
# Define a service to check the disk space of the root partition
# on the local machine.  Warning if < 20% free, critical if
# < 10% free space on partition.
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       myserver
        service_description             Root Partition
    check_command           check_local_disk!20%!10%!/
        }
# Define a service to check the number of currently logged in
# users on the local machine.  Warning if > 20 users, critical
# if > 50 users.
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       myserver
        service_description             Current Users
    check_command           check_local_users!20!50
        }
# Define a service to check the number of currently running procs
# on the local machine.  Warning if > 250 processes, critical if
# > 400 users.
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       myserver
        service_description             Total Processes
    check_command           check_local_procs!250!400!RSZDT
        }
# Define a service to check the load on the local machine. 
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       myserver
        service_description             Current Load
    check_command           check_local_load!5.0,4.0,3.0!10.0,6.0,4.0
        }
# Define a service to check the swap usage the local machine. 
# Critical if less than 10% of swap is free, warning if less than 20% is free
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       myserver
        service_description             Swap Usage
    check_command           check_local_swap!20!10
        }
# Define a service to check SSH on the local machine.
# Disable notifications for this service by default, as not all users may have SSH enabled.
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       myserver
        service_description             SSH
    check_command           check_ssh!-p xx
    notifications_enabled       0
        }
# Define a service to check HTTP on the local machine.
# Disable notifications for this service by default, as not all users may have HTTP enabled.
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       myserver
        service_description             HTTP
    check_command           check_http
    notifications_enabled       0
        }
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               myserver
        service_description     mysql Monitoring
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_mysql
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a `check_mysql` command definition for NRPE.

Edit your nrpe.cfg.

```
vim /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
```

Add a command entry for `check_mysql` pointing to the path of the `check_mysql` plugin:

```
command[check_mysql]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql
```

Restart nrpe:

```
service nrpe restart
```

Check out page 13 for more information:
https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf

Comment: hi, thank you. i fixed this issue adding a tcp check for 3306, because this is a local service, not remote.